# boost NuGet пакет

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, boost, nuget

Добавил `NuGet` пакет `boost 1.65.1` в **Visual Studio 2015 (C++)** и получил ошибку во время компиляции:

> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc140-mt-1_65_1.lib'

Переустановка пакета не помогла. Ошибка наблюдается даже если создать чистый проект и подключить `boost`

Comment: Что делать теперь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:
на сайте boost.org скачиваем библиотеку, компилируем и подключаем ее в Visual Studio инструкции я брал тут 
http://kaktusenok.blogspot.com/2013/08/boost-visual-studio.html
все понятно и просто собралось решение в Releas конфигурации